# Random alphanumeric ID on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to auto-generate random Alphanumeric ID on SQL Server?
If so, please let me know how. What datatype should I use?
I'm using asp.net C# BTW.

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: `SELECT NEWID()` will return a UUID looking something like `dae2e167-6f3e-4d9d-8a1a-53a80242bd1f`.  If you can work with this, then the duplicate link has you covered.  If not, then edit your question and show us what you have in mind here.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking for. Thank you.